# Fitting a multilevel multivariate model in R with `glmer`

Tags: r, multivariate-analysis, multilevel-analysis, multivariate-regression

**Background**

I have a large dataset that contains three binary outcomes for individuals belonging to groups. I am interested in jointly modeling these binary outcomes because I have reason to believe they are positively correlated with one another. Most of my data are at the individual level; however, I also have some group-level information.

Because of the structure of my data, I am treating this as a 3-level logistic regression. The first level defines the multivariate structure through dummy variables that indicate for each outcome. Therefore level-1 accounts for the within-individual measurements. Level-2 provides the between-individuals variances and level-3 gives the between-group variance.

*Hypothetical Example:*

Suppose I have data for students in classrooms. I want to examine whether certain student-level characteristics are important predictors for passing three different pre-tests (math, history, and gym). The pre-tests are constructed such that about half of the students should pass each exam (no floor or ceiling effect). Since some students are better than others, I expect whether or not they pass their history exam to be correlated to their probability of passing their math and gym pre-tests. I also expect that students in the same classroom will perform more similarly than students across classrooms.

**Here is my attempt at writing out the model**

I use $h$ to index level-1, $i$ to index level-2, and $j$ to index level-3. Recall that level-1 corresponds to within-individual, level-2 corresponds to between-individuals, and level-3 corresponds to between-groups. So, I have $h$ measures for the $i^\text{th}$ individual in the $j^\text{th}$ group.

Let 
\begin{align}
\alpha_{1ij} &= 1 \text{ if outcome}_1 = 1 \text{ and 0 otherwise} \\
\alpha_{2ij} &= 1 \text{ if outcome}_2 = 1 \text{ and 0 otherwise} \\
\alpha_{3ij} &= 1 \text{ if outcome}_3 = 1 \text{ and 0 otherwise}
\end{align}

\begin{align}
\text{log}\left( \frac{\pi_{hij}}{1 - \pi_{hij}} \right) &= \alpha_{0hij} + \alpha_{1hij}Z_{ij} + \eta_h \\
Z_{ij} &= \beta_{0ij} + X_{ij}\beta_{ij} + U_{j} + \epsilon_i \\
U_{j} &= \gamma_{0j} + X_{j}\gamma_{j}
 + \rho_j
\end{align}

Please leave suggestions about this notation; I am not positive that it is correct.

**Trying to specify the model in R**

I have been using R 3.0.1, but am open to solutions using other standard software (e.g. SAS, Stata, WinBUGs, etc.). Since I am modeling a binary response, I am using the `glmer` function in the `lme4` package.

My data set is in long format, with one row per outcome per individual per group.

One of my current problems is correctly specifying a 3-level model. Given 5 individual-level measures and one group-level measure, I have tried to specify the model as:

```
> glmer(pi ~ outcome1:(x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + u5) + 
             outcome2:(x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + u5) +
             outcome3:(x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + u5) +
             (1 + x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 | individual) +
             (1 + u5 | group), family=binomial, data=pretest)
```

but this often produces warnings and does not converge.

**My questions**

1. Does my approach make sense? (i.e. does it make sense to model a multilevel multivariate model by specifying the multivariate structure in the first level?)
2. I have difficult with the proper notation and appreciate suggestions for clarifying my notation.
3. Am I using the right tools for this problem? Should I be using other packages or software?

Thanks in advance for your suggestions and advice.

Comment: Where did you get the idea to model the multivariate responses this way? What is `pi`?

Comment: I got the idea from a chapter in a book – which was only briefly described so I am not certain my interpretation is correct. `pi` is a binary response indicator; I didn't want to use `y` since it is sort of confusing with `outcome`.

Comment: I was looking for a little more detail, like a title or author. I wonder if what you're trying to fit is a *multinomial* model.

Comment: Sorry. The title is *Multilevel Statistical Models* by Harvey Goldstein. Since I have several associated binary indicators, I thought these were best modeled using multivariate models, not multinomial.

Comment: I think I understand. I believe `outcome{1,2,3}` are actually supposed to be indicators of the outcome represented by `pi`, not the outcome measurement itself--`pi` captures that. Then the parameter estimates for them are the outcome specific intercepts (thus, exclude the standard intercept with `+0`). Then to model the correlation between the outcomes, you need allow the intercepts to vary randomly and correlate with a term like `(outcome1+outcome2+outcome3+0|individual)`. This is a comment because I am not comfortable enough with the procedure to make it an "answer".

Comment: Exactly. This is my understanding for `outcome` and `pi`. However, I want to be sure this method is appropriate and hopefully hear some suggestions about how to implement this.